# Can I specialize a class template with an alias template?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, template-aliases

Here's a simple example:

```
class bar {};

template <typename>
class foo {};

template <>
using foo<int> = bar;
```

Is this allowed?

Comment: How is this different from `typedef foo<int> bar;`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's the complete opposite. This would be more like `typedef bar foo<int>;` (though this is not allowed). In my example, `bar` already exists as a type, and `foo<int>` becomes a new name for it. (What you wrote is equivalent to `using bar = foo<int>;`, if that helps.)

Comment: Oh, I see. But then you might as well ask for *any* class definition to be copyable: `class Foo = Bar;` etc. I don't suppose that's possible...

Comment: `using Foo = Bar;`? (Or `typedef Bar Foo;`, if you prefer the old style.) I don't expect my example (if valid) to create a distinct type (please let me know I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: Hmm, reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622452/alias-template-specialisation/6623089#6623089 makes me believe this is indeed not possible.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking about *copying* the type definition, not just aliasing, since I imagine that you'd have to provide (the equivalent of) a full class definition for an explicit specialization. The linked answer does indeed suggest that aliases are not the right tool for the job.

Comment: I wrote a few `define`s that generalize on Aotium's answer, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14050604/225186

Comment: There is slightly indirect way. see [Section 1.4](http://www.stroustrup.com/template-aliases.pdf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ clang++ -std=c++0x test.cpp
test.cpp:6:1: error: explicit specialization of alias templates is not permitted
template <>
^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Reference: 14.1 [temp.decls]/p3:

> 3 Because an alias-declaration cannot declare a template-id, it is not
>   possible to partially or explicitly specialize an alias template.

Comment: Is that clang 3.0?  OK I see from the clang pages that my clang 2.9 won't work.

Answer (score 11):

Although direct specialization of the alias is impossible, here is a workaround.
(I know this is an old post but it's a useful one.)

You can create a template struct with a typedef member, and specialize the struct.
You can then create an alias that refers to the typedef member.

```
template <typename T>
struct foobase {};

template <typename T>
struct footype
  { typedef foobase<T> type; };

struct bar {};

template <>
struct footype<int>
  { typedef bar type; };

template <typename T>
using foo = typename footype<T>::type;

foo<int> x; // x is a bar.
```

This lets you specialize `foo` indirectly by specializing `footype`.

You could even tidy it up further by inheriting from a remote class that automatically provides the typedef. However, some may find this more of a hassle. Personally, I like it.

```
template <typename T>
struct remote
  { typedef T type; };

template <>
struct footype<float> :
  remote<bar> {};

foo<float> y; // y is a bar.
```

Comment: I have been using this trick, but it does help to have it out here. So, thanks for putting it up. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Just after writing a long answer with workaround for this limitation, I found your answer that uses the same principle. In any case I wrote in addition a couple of `define`s to make the code shorter. Take a look if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14050604/225186

Comment: I think you missed a `<T>` in the `using` statement: `template <typename T> using foo = typename footype<T>::type;`

Answer (score 7):

According to §14.7.3/1 of the standard (also referred to in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622452/alias-template-specialisation/6622494#6622494)), aliases are not allowed as explicit specializations :(

> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>
> - function template
> - class template
> - member function of a class template
> - static data member of a class template
> - member class of a class template
> - member class template of a class or class template
> - member function template of a class or class template
>
> can be declared[...]