# partial template member specialization

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Given the following definitions:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class A {

public:

   void f();

};

template <typename T>
void
A<T>::f()
{}

template <typename T>
class B {};
```

How would I partially specialize `A<B<T>>::f`, i.e. `f` for some `B<T>`? I'm basically looking for the *right magic* to substitute the `???` below

```cpp
template <???>
void
A<B<T>>::f()
{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an *explicit* specialization, from [temp.expl.spec]:

> An explicit specialization of any of the following:
>   — ...
>   — member function of a class template
>   — ...
>   can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>`

That is:

```
template <>
void A<B<int>>::f() {
    std::cout << "B\n";
}
```

But you cannot have a partial specialization of a member function of a class template. You would have to partially specialize the entire class:

```
template <typename T>
class A<B<T>> {
public:
    void f() {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }

    // ... all other members you want in A<B<T>> ...
};
```

Comment: do you know where in the standard this is made explicit, i.e. no partial specialization of a member function of a class template allowed?

Comment: @regnirpsj It's sort of implied by "The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial specialization shall match the template
parameter list of the class template partial specialization. The template argument list of a member of a class
template partial specialization shall match the template argument list of the class template partial specialization."

Comment: Thanks. I never really liked the lawyerese in  standard but after some parsing it makes sense.

Comment: @regnirpsj you may also check **14.8 Function template specializations [temp.fct.spec]**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partially specialize a member function (nor in fact any function). You need to partially specialize the whole class:

```
template<typename T>
class A<B<T>>
{
    // implement member functions for this specialization here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have:

```
template <typename T>
void A<B<typename T>>::f() {}
```

then your only choice is to partially specialize `A`.

```
template <typename T> class A<B<T>>
{
   public:
      void f();
};
```

Answer (score -2):

C++11 has [Alias Templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), allowing you do do something like:

```
template<T>
using AB = A<B<T>>;
```

Then you can refer to `AB<T>` instead of `A<B<T>>`.

Unfortunately, [you can't use that for specialization.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801370/871910).

So seems to me the answer to your question is: You can't do that, but it's a shame.

Comment: What do alias templates have to do with the OP's problem?

Comment: They're the first half of the solution.

Comment: I have no idea how they're the first half of a solution, given that you may not partially specialize member functions. If it were allowed, it'd probably be just `template<typename T> void A<B<T>>::f() {}`