# How do template aliases affect template parameter deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-aliases

In C++03, template parameter deduction does not occur in some contexts. For example:

```
template <typename T> struct B {};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef B<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
void f(typename A<T>::type);

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    f(b);  // ERROR: no match
}
```

Here, `int` is not deduced for `T`, because a nested type such as `A<T>::type` is a non-deduced context.

Had I written the function like this:

```
template <typename T> struct B {};

template <typename T>
void f(B<T>);

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    f(b);
}
```

everything is fine because `B<T>` **is** a deduced context.

In C++11, however, template aliases can be used to disguise a nested type in syntax similar to the second example. For example:

```
template <typename T> struct B {};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef B<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
using C = typename A<T>::type;

template <typename T>
void f(C<T>);

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    f(b);
}
```

Would template argument deduction work in this case? In other words, are template aliases a deduced context or a non-deduced context? Or do they inherit the deduced/non-deduced status of whatever they alias?

Comment: Aliases are just aliases. It's like writing `template <typename T> void f(typename A<T>::type);`, which isn't deducible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, template argument can not be deduced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Comment: I'd think Kerrek SB is correct about this. If had provided a quote I wouldn't need to go off and search one ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't think it is a duplicate: this is about template aliases and I can't see any hint of template aliases in the question you pointed to.

Comment: @Nawaz: please actually read the question before marking it a duplicate...

Comment: Oops. I misread the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In other words, are template aliases a deduced context or a non-deduced context?

They are as deducible as the equivalent code without using template aliases. For example

```
template<typename T>
using ref = T&;

template<typename T>
void f(ref<T> r);
```

Now you can call `f(x)` and `T` will be deduced perfectly fine. At the definition time of `f` already, `ref<T>` is replaced by type `T&`. And `T&` is a deduced context.

In your case `C<T>` is replaced by `typename A<T>::type`, and that is a non-deduced context for `T`, so `T` cannot be deduced.

Comment: The key phrase in Johannes' excellent answer is “At the *definition time* of `f` already” (emphasis mine).  It's easy to miss that, but knowing it explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo { typedef   T type; }
template <> struct Foo<char>     { typedef int type; }

template <typename T> using mytype = typename Foo<T>::type;

template <typename T> void f(mytype<T>);
```

Now if I want `int n; f(n);`, how could I decide whether I want `T = int` or `T = char`? The whole problem, which is unaffected by template aliases, is that you cannot deduce *backwards* to all the things that could possibly define something.

Answer (score 1):

I think the relevant quote in the C++ standard is 14.5.7 [temp.alias] paragraph 2:

> When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the type-id of the alias template. [ Note: An alias template name is never deduced. — end note ]

There is an example following the quote which effectively spells out that it is pointless to use an alias template in a function template and hoping to deduce the template argument. This apparently applies even for situation which don't involve nested types.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. What your quote regarding deduction says is that the alias template name cannot be deduced. That is `template<template<typename T> class C> void f(C<T>); ref<int> r; f(r);` is not possible to deduce `C == ref` (given my definition of `ref` in my answer). It does not mean what you conclude it means.

Comment: OK, I can accept this. However, yesterday I haven't found a better quotes (but I may have been confuddled). Can you point me towards a quote in the standard?

Comment: you quoted it yourself. The template-id `ref<T>` is equivalent to `T&` by the quote you have given. And hence the non-normative note says that it is unusable to deduce `ref`. But it is usable for deducing `T`, because of this early-replacement. See the solution of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#395 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6623089/34509