# Does C++11 support types recursion in templates?

Tags: c++, types, c++11, type-theory

I want to explain the question in detail. In many languages with strong type systems (like Felix, Ocaml, Haskell) you can define a polymorphic list by composing type constructors. Here's the Felix definition:

```
typedef list[T] = 1 + T * list[T];
typedef list[T] = (1 + T * self) as self;
```

In Ocaml:

```ml
type 'a list = Empty | Cons ('a, 'a list)
```

In C, this is recursive but neither polymorphic nor compositional:

```
struct int_list { int elt; struct int_list *next; };
```

In C++ it would be done like this, if C++ supported type recursion:

```
struct unit {};
template<typename T>
    using list<T> = variant< unit, tuple<T, list<T>> >;
```

given a suitable definition for tuple (aka pair) and variant (but not the broken one used in Boost). Alternatively:

```
    using list<T> = variant< unit, tuple<T, &list<T>> >;
```

might be acceptable given a slightly different definition of variant. It was not possible to even write this in C++ < C++11 because without template typedefs, there's no way to get polymorphism, and without a sane syntax for typedefs, there's no way to get the target type in scope. The using syntax above solves both these problems, however this does not imply recursion is permitted.

In particular please note that allowing recursion has a major impact on the ABI, i.e. on name mangling (it can't be done unless the name mangling scheme allows for representation of fixpoints).

My question: is required to work in C++11?
[Assuming the expansion doesn't result in an infinitely large struct]

---

Edit: just to be clear, the requirement is for general structural typing. Templates provide precisely that, for example

```
pair<int, double>
pair<int, pair <long, double> >
```

are anonymously (structurally) typed, and pair is clearly polymorphic. However recursion in C++ < C++11 cannot be stated, not even with a pointer. In C++11 you can state the recursion, albeit with a template typedef (with the new using syntax the expression on the LHS of the = sign is in scope on the RHS).

Structural (anonymous) typing with polymorphism and recursion are minimal requirements for a type system.

Any modern type system must support polynomial type functors or the type system is too clumbsy to do any kind of high level programming. The combinators required for this are usually stated by type theoreticians like:

```
1 | * | + | fix
```

where 1 is the unit type, * is tuple formation, + is variant formation, and fix is recursion. The idea is simply that:

if t is a type and u is a type then t + u and t * u are also types

In C++, struct unit{} is 1, tuple  is *, variant  is + and fixpoints might be obtained with the using = syntax. It's not quite anonymous typing because the fixpoint would require a template typedef.

---

Edit: Just an example of polymorphic type constructor in C:

```
T*          // pointer formation
T (*)(U)    // one argument function type
T[2]        // array
```

Unfortunately in C, function values aren't compositional, and pointer formation is subject to lvalue constraint, and the syntactic rules for type composition are not themselves compositional, but here we can say:

```
if T is a type T* is a type
if T and U are types, T (*)(U) is a type
if T is a type T[2] is a type
```

so these type constuctors (combinators) can be applied recursively to get new types without having to create a new intermediate type. In C++ we can easily fix the syntactic problem:

```
template<typename T> using ptr<T> = T*;
template<typename T, typename U> using fun<T,U> = T (*)(U);
template<typename T> using arr2<T> = T[2];
```

so now you can write:

```
arr2<fun<double, ptr<int>>>
```

and the syntax is compositional, as well as the typing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you start a question with *in a decent language* you are up to get some heat... At any rate, you should state what you want to do, *types recursion* does not really ring a bell as to what you want to achieve. What do you mean with *polymorphic* and *compositional*?

Comment: @KerrekSB: structural typing with polymorphism, which is precisely what templates were designed for, but they never supported type recursion which is essential.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Obviously, he wants to achieve creating recursive template aliases. The question could be, however, stated less harshly.

Comment: "*variant (but not the broken one used in Boost)*" In what way is it broken? The fact that it's implemented in C++, which you seem to dislike?

Comment: @ildjarn: last I looked Boost variant is broken because it only allows one variant of each type, therefore it isn't a proper sum (variant) type. Variants must allow any number of cases with the same argument types. The most trivial example of a variant is an enumeration, for which there are no arguments at all.

Comment: It doesn't _claim_ to be "a proper sum (variant) type", so it isn't broken, it just doesn't do what _you_ want.

Comment: @ildjam: that is true, but it isn't me that imposes the requirement but type theory. The failure of Boost tuple to implement a proper tuple type is precisely what drove the implementors to put variadic templates in the C++11 Standard. In that sense, tuple was broken but can now be properly implemented. In that sense, variant remains broken.

Comment: @Yttrill: this question would be very interesting if you pulled out all the hyperbole and bullshit about "requirements for being able to do any high level programming". As it is, it's just flamebait

Comment: @Yttrill : Regarding variants, fair enough; the way it's worded in your question is quite abrasive, but your elaboration is more reasonable.

Comment: @jalf: Sometimes its useful to be a bit abrasive. Programming issues aren't entirely technical. They're also political.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you stopped mixing up two separate concepts. The first is: can I express this type in the type system? The answer is simple: no, C++'s type system is far too basic to natively support what you want. Nothing more to that. The second is: how can this type be implemented? That's an entirely different question, and depends on a particular concrete instance, not a hypothetical question. Your issue seems to be that you think the two have to occur at the same time. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Yttrill I suppose you want to attract technically skilled answerers? Then cut the political crap, because it will only push them away.

Comment: @Yttrill: no. It would be political and potentially beneficial) to be "abrasive" at the C++ standards commitee. Accosting random programmers just to tell them that C++ sucks because it didn't have the same design goals as Haskell seems less useful. Trying to disguise a language flamewar beneath a question that *could* have been legitimate is not useful, and it is not political.

Comment: @Yttrill: "Programming issues aren't entirely technical. They're also political." Being abrasive for a "political" issue is *even worse*. Being abrasive for a touchy, personal subject only makes people stop listening to what you have to say.

Comment: @Everyone: point about being abrasive accepted.

Comment: @GManNickG: It was the simple answer you refer to I wanted, I simply didn't know. I emailed Bjarne but he didn't reply. As to implementing the type, I need a mechanical way to generate type *names* for polynomial types. I am already generating the types, that's easy. The problem is the names generated differ in two compilation units: I don't have a way to generate sufficiently short readable names deterministically from the types. I hoped to use template names and let the C++ name mangler do its thing.

Comment: Just to be more specific for list<int> I generate `struct _1675 { int mem0; _1675 *mem1; }` from the functional specification. No problem, except in the next translation unit I generate `struct _2312 { int mem0; _2312 *mem1; }` and so a function like `int add(_1675)` can't be shared across translation units because the type names differ.

Comment: Why do you say that Boost's variant is broken?

Comment: Because as far as I can tell, it only allows one case per type. A real variant does not have this restriction. Apart from that using it is a super PITA compared to a real variant, particularly since C++ doesn't have pattern matching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Even indirect recursion through alias templates is forbidden.

C++11, 4.5.7/3:

> The type-id in an alias template declaration shall not refer to the alias template being declared. The type produced by an alias template specialization shall not directly or indirectly make use of that specialization. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct A;
> template <class T> using B = typename A<T>::U;
> template <class T> struct A {
> typedef B<T> U;
> };
> B<short> b; // error: instantiation of B<short> uses own type via A<short>::U
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: I am sad. Can you, by chance, cite the C++11 Standard text that excludes this? I would hope there's a specific exclusion, because when experimental implementations are made to work there's a simple target for subsequent relaxation of the restriction. It can certainly be done: my programming language Felix can do it, and it generates C++. In fact, my main problem is that there's no canonical name for such types which makes dynamic linkage rather hard to achieve.

Answer (score 10):

If you want this, stick to your Felix, Ocaml, or Haskell. You will easily realize that very few (none?) sucessful languages have type systems as rich as those three. And in my opinion, if all languages were the same, learning new ones wouldn't be worth it.

```
template<typename T>
using list<T> = variant< unit, tuple<T, list<T>> >;
```

In C++ doesn't work because an alias template doesn't define a new type. It's purely an alias, a synonym, and it *is equivalent to its substitution*. [This is a *feature*, btw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623089/46642).

That alias template is equivalent to the following piece of Haskell:

```hs
type List a = Either () (a, List a)
```

GHCi rejects this because "[cycles] in type synonym declarations" are not allowed. I'm not sure if this is outright banned in C++, or if it is allowed but causes infinite recursion when substituted. Either way, it doesn't work.

The way to define new types in C++ is with the `struct`, `class`, `union`, and `enum` keywords. If you want something like the following Haskell (I insist on Haskell examples, because I don't know the other two languages), then you need to use those keywords.

```hs
newtype List a = List (Either () (a, List a))
```

Comment: Interesting, Haskell doesn't support structural typing? I'm not a Haskell programmer (though I can read some of it :) Actually C++ has a very rich and exceptionally powerful type system, even if it's a bit broken. For example, typed offsets, pointers, arrays and classes at the lower level, and genuine though very badly typed polyadic programming (functorial polymorphism). The STL actually relies on that (generalising over data structures using iterators).

Comment: @Yttrill No, Haskell doesn't support structural typing. It's possible that there's a GHC extension that helps, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Just make sure I understand what "structural typing" is, `newtype Foo a = Foo (Either () (a, Foo a))` would define a type that is distinct from the type `List a` in the last example in my answer, because they have different names. Passing one into a function expecting the other is an error. It is my understanding that with structural typing the two would be the same because they have the same structure, and could be used interchangeably. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. Of course Haskell does have *some* structural typing because `List int` is a type name. However the data functor List can only be nominally typed. Roughly I think structural typing is just a matter of "canonical" names for type expressions.

Comment: +1 Better than the accepted answer. This post actually explains from a theoretical standpoint why this can't work and indeed why it doesn't work in Haskell the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to review your type theory, as several of your assertions are incorrect.

Let's address your main question (and backhanded point) - as others have pointed out type recursion *of the type you requested* is not allowed.  This does **not** mean that c++ does not support type recursion.  It supports it perfectly well.  The type recursion you requested is type *name* recursion, which is a syntactic flair that actually has no consequence on the actual type system.

C++ allows tuple membership recursion by proxy.  For instance, c++ allows

```
class A
{
    A * oneOfMe_;
};
```

That is type recursion that has real consequences.  (And obviously no language can do this without internal proxy representation because size is infinitely recursive otherwise).

Also C++ allows translationtime polymorphism, which allow for the creation of objects that act like any type you may create using name recursion.  The name recursion is only used to unload types to members or provide translationtime behavior assignments in the type system.  Type tags, type traits, etc. are well known c++ idioms for this.

To prove that type name recursion does not add functionality to a type system, it only needs to be pointed out that c++'s type system allows a fully Turing Complete type calculation, using metaprogramming on compiletime constants (and typelists of them), through simple mapping of names to constants.  This means there is a function MakeItC++:YourIdeaOfPrettyName->TypeParametrisedByTypelistOfInts that makes any Turing computible typesystem you want.

As you know, being a student of type theory, variants are dual to tuple products.  In the type category, any property of variants has a dual property of tuple products with arrows reversed.  If you work consistently with the duality, you do not get properties with "new capabilities" (in terms of type calculations).  So on the level of type calculations, you obviously don't *need* variants.  (This should also be obvious from the Turing Completeness.)

However, in terms of runtime behavior in an imperative language, you do get different behavior.  And it is bad behavior.  Whereas products restrict semantics, variants relax semantics.  You should never want this, as it *provably* destroys code correctness.  The history of statically typed programming languages has been moving towards greater and greater expression of the semantics in the type system, with the goal that the compiler should be able to understand when the program does not mean what you want it to.  The goal has been to turn the compiler into the program verification system.

For instance, with type units, you can express that a particular value isn't just an `int` but is actually an acceleration measured in meters per square seconds.  Assigning a value that is a velocity expressed in feet per hour divided by a timespan of minutes shouldn't just divide the two values - it should note that a conversion is necessary (and either perform it or fail compilation or... do the right thing).  Assinging a force should fail compilation.  Doing these kinds of checks on program meaning could have given us potentially more martian exploration, for instance.

Variants are the opposite direction.  Sure, "if you code correctly, they work correctly", but that's not the point with code verification.  They provably add code loci where a different engineer, unfamiliar with current type usage, can introduce the incorrect semantic assumption without translation failure.  And, there is always a code transformation that changes an imperative code section from one that uses Variants unsafely to one that use semantically validated non-variant types, so their use is also "always suboptimal".

The majority of runtime uses for variants are typically those that are better encapsulated in runtime polymorphism.  Runtime polymorphism has a statically verified semantics that may have associated runtime invariant checking and unlike variants (where the sum type is universally declared in one code locus) actually supports the Open-Closed principle.  By needing to declare a variant in one location, you must change that location everytime you add a new functional type to the sum.  This means that code never closes to change, and therefore may have bugs introduced.  Runtime polymorphism, though, allows new behaviors to be added in separate code loci from the other behaviors.

(And besides, most real language type systems are not distributive anyway.  (a, b | c) =/= (a, b) | (a, c) so what is the point here?)

I would be careful making blanket statements about what makes a type system good without getting some experience in the field, particularly if your point is to be provocative and political and enact change.  I do not see anything in your post that actually points to healthy changes for any computer language.  I do not see features, safety, or any of the other actual real-world concerns being addressed.  I totally get the love of type theory.  I think every computer scientist should know Cateogry Theory and the denotational semantics of programming languages (domain theory, cartesian categories, all the good stuff).  I think if more people understood the Curry-Howard isomorphism as an ontological manifesto, constructivist logics would get more respect.

But none of that provides reasons to attack the c++ type system.  There are legitimate attacks for nearly every language - type name recursion and variant availability are not them.

---

EDIT: Since my point about Turing completeness does not seem to be understood, nor my comment about the c++ way of using type tags and traits to offload type calculations, maybe an example is in order.

Now the OP claims to want this in a usage case for lists, which my earlier point on the layout easily handles.  Better, just use std::list.  But from other comments and elsewhere, I think they really want this to work on the Felix->C++ translation.

So, what I think the OP thinks they want is something like

```
template <typename Type>
class SomeClass
{
    // ...
};
```

and then be able to build a type

```
SomeClass< /*insert the SomeClass<...> type created here*/ >
```

I've mentioned this is just a naming convention wanted.  Nobody wants typenames - they are transients of the translation process.  What is actually wanted is what you will do with Type later on in the structural composition of the type.  It will be used in typename calculations to produce member data and method signatures.

So, what can be done in c++ is

```
struct SelfTag {};
```

Then, when you want to refer to self, just put this type tag there.

When it's meaningful to do the type calculation, you have a template specialisation on `SelfTag` that will substitute `SomeClass<SelfTag>` instead of substituting `SelfTag` in the appropriate place of the type calculation.

My point here is that the c++ type system is Turing Complete - and that means a lot more than what I think the OP is reading everytime I've written that.  **Any type calculation may be done** (given constraints of compiler recursion) **and that really does mean that if you have a problem in one type system in a completely different language, you can find a translation here**.  I hope this makes things even clearer about my point.  Coming back and saying "well you still can't do XYZ in the type system" would be clearly missing the point.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-read my question. The issue isn't whether C++ allows type recursion, I pointed out myself that even C does. The issue is whether templates allow it, and they don't: in particular the requirement is for polymorphism, composability in the sense of combinators, and recursion.

Comment: Also you're wrong about run time polymorphism in two distinct sense. Variants are closed, and modification breaks stuff, which is precisely what one may desire. It's what make my Ocaml code work without bugs (provided I don't use wildcards). OTOH, whilst virtual function dispatch certainly provides open/closed behaviour, it's applicability is limited to attributes by the covariance problem, so this is not a general solution: virtual function polymorphism DOES NOT WORK for most interesting problems.

Comment: As to "needing" variants, I think you misunderstand what programmers need (as do almost all programmers). Assembler is clearly enough to code anything: need is not defined by computing capability but how it is expression. However I do ask if you can explain more your point about safety of variants?

Comment: @Yttrill: Templates allow the same type recursion I mentioned.  That's why I didn't use templates, to not confuse the issue.  You are looking for a type name recursion, which is only useful in type calculations for building actual types.  C++ has a complete type calculation system.  Complete.  As in it does every type calculation you could want.  Not with the same type name syntax you want, but with it's own.  You aren't asking for anything that can't be done, you just don't like the way it's done.

Comment: @Yttrill: I point out how type systems have been evolving (in enforcing semantics over the bare "layout problem" of assembly), and you assume I don't realise why assembly is not enough?  You have stopped thinking about what I've said and have started replying out of instinctual defensive modes.  I can't reason with you if you aren't reading what I'm writing.  Do you have a comment on the semantic enforcement of type systems, or are you just going to respond with other words that make you feel good but have nothing to do with my point?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to create recursive types structurally. You can make products in C and C++ with structs. Sure. But you can make them structurally with a tuple<> template too: I guess the field names are just integers then. I need to do recursion the same way: structurally. Why? Because I wan't to have structural types in two translation units agree on their canonical names, otherwise they can't link together.

Comment: BTW of course I'm sure you know more type theory than me. However the lack of type recursion in templates definitely IS a reason to attack the C++ type system IMHO. The *whole* advantage of templates is composability. Instead of list_int, you can do list<int> without needing to declare a new type. But it isn't general enough: it can't even parametrise what C can do: C does recursion by incomplete types later completed. Templates can and should allow this too but they don't (I mean, the type parameters not the class definitions).

Comment: @Yttrill: I've edited my response with an actual solution for your particular needs, to show you that there is no missing "advantage of composability" and that the comment "Templates can and should allow this too but they don't" is wrong.

Comment: don't see how that helps. And BTW I knew templates were Turing complete long before you did: I was physically present at the ISO Standards meeting where it was joyously discovered by experiment.

Comment: @exOdu5: could you send me an email s k a l l e r at user dot sourceforge dot n e t

Comment: woops, that's users not user ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

C++ does have the "curiously recurring template pattern", or CRTP. It's not specific to C++11, however. It means you can do the following (shamelessly copied from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)):

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    // ...
};
struct derived : base<derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Yes, this allows "defer"ing completion, as does C "struct X" where X isn't defined yet. That provides recursion, but you have to use named types (nominal typing). If you could do this to implement a recursive polymorphic type systematically it would be nice, but your class derived is an recursive instance, it isn't polymorphic, so you can't write interesting polymorphic algorithms (templated functions).

Comment: @Yttrill: "so you can't write interesting polymorphic algorithms (templated functions)": It's not that bad. You can't write typed generic functions with recursive types, but you there aren't any universal types anyway and templates arent typed, so who cares. In reality, you just take whatever type you get and use it through a known interface. So writing functions that take types `T` where `T <: base<T>` is possible.

Comment: Actually it is that bad unfortunately. IMHO. Allow me to set you an interesting problem (which is, in fact, my actual problem): for any polynomial type, give me a canonical name. For example for `1 + T * x as x`, which is a functional list, the name I would like to use is a direct mapping to templates: `template<class T, class X> fix<X, variant2 < unit, tuple2<T,X>>>`. I actually only care about the name in my application: I'm doing the type recursion, I just can't link the same types across translation units.

Comment: Just to explain the above: I need to systematically generate names for structural types. I can't "write" code that works, I have to write code that writes the code. Of course if C++ actually supported type recursion in templates my translator be less useful because that's one of the flaws in C++ it is designed to correct.

Answer (score 0):

@jpalcek answered my question. However, my actual problem (as hinted at in the examples) can be solved without recursive aliases like this:

```
// core combinators
struct unit;
struct point;
template<class T,class U> struct fix;
template<class T, class U> struct tup2;
template<class T, class U> struct var2;

template <> struct   
  fix<
    point,
    var2<unit, tup2<int,point> > 
  > 
{ 
  // definition goes here
};
```

using the fix and point types to represent recursion. I happen not to require any of the templates to be defined, I only need to define the specialisations. What I needed was a *name* that would be the same in two distinct translation units for external linkage: the name had to be a function of the type structure.

@Ex0du5 prompted thinking about this. The actual solution is also related to a correspondence from Gabriel des Rois many years ago. I want to thank everyone that contributed.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example of how you would use this code?

Comment: My problem is to get a unique name for an arbitrary combination of and variants, including recursion (since that describe a very wide set of useful datatype). So the definition of the above would be { struct fix<point,var2<unit,tup2<uint,point>>> *next; point data; }

Comment: This is just a singly linked list "(unit + point * self) as self", which is the code from which the above is generated. I cannot name it "list" because its just a type expression.

Comment: I'm sure you have an idea what use singly linked lists have, they're one of the core types used in functional programming. There are many such types, most of which can be defined in one line. A binary tree is just 1 + T * self * self as self. Etc. Collectively these types are called polynomial types.

Comment: Grrr .. above should read "combination of tuples and variants".

Comment: This uses the 5 combinators above? Is that 2 definitions? I get an error; `point`, has an incomplete type.

Comment: Should be struct unit {}; struct point {}; and the "int" should be unit. If you want to understand variants look at Ocaml, Haskell, or Felix. These all have proper variants and pattern matching.

Comment: Why are `next` and `data` declared within a compound statement?

Comment: It's not a compound statement, its the bit from the displayed code between the { and } where it says "// definition goes here". So its the declaration of the two struct members. Sorry for confusion these comments aren't long enough to explain.

Comment: Should the `point` class have members? Anyway, thanks for the clarification. So, I thought you wanted to avoid pointers? Why is your `fix` system different than good old: `struct Abc {
  Abc *next;
  int data;
};` ? Also, do you need the `struct` keyword in the definition?

Comment: Where did you get the name "Abc" from? That is the problem! What we have is a data structure specified by composition of parts: list = var2<unit, tup<int,list>>. If this data structure is used in two compilation units, the two instances must have the same C++ external (mangled) name. The programmer does not name the data structure, just like they do not name a C++ vector of int, that's called vector<int>, just as mine is called fix<var2<unit, tup<int,point>>>. The C++ programmer can use an alias: typedef basic_string<char> string, but string isn't an external name.