# Transforming these templates to Alias Declarations

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, templates, c++17

I've got a few templates based on compile time constants, like this:

```
const int SIG0 = 0;

template<int Sig>
struct SignalPrototype;

template<>
struct SignalPrototype<SIG0> {
  typedef std::function< void() > type;
};
```

When I tried to transform it into the C++11 (I believe) Alias Declarations, I couldn't get it to work in any shape or form (posting just one of them):

```
const int SIG0 = 0;

template<int Sig>
using SignalPrototype = std::function< void() >;

template<>
using SignalPrototype<SIG0> = std::function< void() >;
```

With the error: `expected unqualified-id before ‘using’`
I guess it is expecting something in the template parameters, but I can't put `SIG0` as it is not a type.

Notes:
I'm using C++ standard up to C++17, so anything newer that I don't know about is appreciated too.

Also, I don't like the 'these' in the title, but I have no idea what is their specific name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that are wrong here.
`const int SIG0 = 0;` needs to be a `constexpr` rather then `const`.
And you [cannot specialize alias templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623089/2640636).

What you could do is combine the two approaches like this:

```
constexpr int SIG0 = 0;

template <int Sig> struct SignalPrototype;
template<> struct SignalPrototype<SIG0> {
  typedef std::function< void() > type;
};

template <int Sig>
using SignalPrototype_t = typename SignalPrototype<Sig>::type;
```

Comment: I indeed could do that, I'll look if it fits my specific code - or of it even helps with readability (which is mainly what I'm after)

Comment: @areuz The `std` namespace in C++14 includes a lot of aliases like the `SignalPrototype_t` I suggested, which weren't there in C++11. So it seems that people find them useful. I use them myself too, because they spare you from typing `typename` and `::type` all the time. Here are some examples from the `type_traits` header: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits Scroll down through the Synopsis section.