# Why is sfinae on if constexpr not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++17

The detection idiom works as follows

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_foo {static constexpr bool value = false;};
template<typename T>
struct has_foo<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::foo)>> {static constexpr bool value = true;};
template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_foo_v = has_foo<T>::value;
```

And then we can detect the presence of `foo` in any type `T`.

```
if constexpr(has_foo_v<decltype(var)>)
    var.foo();
```

My problem is, that is quite a lot to type (read: want to smash my keyboard a lot to type), and I wondered if the following is possible

```
if constexpr(std::void_t<decltype(&decltype(var)::foo)>(), true)
    var.foo();
```

It is not.

Is there a reason behind this?
More specifically, what trade-offs will have to be made if this were allowed?

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/2069064). One answer might be because there's no substitution here, so how can there be SFINAE? Another answer might be because it wasn't considered since the proposals were always about the `if` taking a `bool`?

Comment: @Barry Hopefully edited question into a form that can have a clear answer. Was originally thinking about something along the lines of [this kind of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623089/4832499)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of pointer to member function is a bad idea; if `foo` is overloaded, it spuriously fails (you have a foo, but not just one).  Who really wants "do you have exactly one foo"?  Almost nobody.

Here is a briefer version:

```
template<class T>
using dot_foo_r = decltype( std::declval<T>().foo() );

template<class T>
using can_foo = can_apply<dot_foo_r, T>;
```

where

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

Now, writing `dot_foo_r` is a bit annoying.

With `constexpr` lambdas we can make it less annoying and do it inline.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

It does need the `RETURNS` macro, at least until @Barry's submission to `[](auto&&f)RETURNS(f())` be equivalent to `[](auto&&f)=>f()`.

We then write `can_invoke`, which is a `constexpr` variant of `std::is_invocable`:

```
template<class F>
constexpr auto can_invoke( F&& f ) {
  return [](auto&&...args)->std::is_invocable<F(decltype(args)...)>{
    return {};
  };
}
```

This gives us:

```
if constexpr(
  can_invoke([](auto&&var) RETURNS(var.foo()))(var)
) {
  var.foo();
}
```

or using @Barry's proposed C++20 syntax:

```
if constexpr(can_invoke(var=>var.foo())(var)) {
  var.foo();
}
```

and we are done.

The trick is that `RETURNS` macro (or `=>` C++20 feature) lets us do SFINAE on an expression.  The lambda becomes an easy way to carry that expression around as a value.

You could write

```
    [](auto&&var) ->decltype(var.foo()) { return var.foo(); }
```

but I think `RETURNS` is worth it (and I don't like macros).

Comment: Was just thinking about including this case as a different kind of motivating example in the next draft. `if constexpr(can_invoke_f<T>(x => x.foo())) { ... }` still isn't exactly ideal compared to what OP wanted, but it's not bad.

Comment: @Barry Got rid of a `decltype` and improved `can_invoke`; `can_invoke` now takes a function instance `f` and returns a `constexpr` invoke-tester on `f`.  Freel free to steal/adapt; I think it is much slicker now.

Comment: What's the `=>` syntax?

Comment: I'm also quite excited about the new syntax. Is the proposal publicly available somewhere?

Comment: @jona http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r0.html -- that version was not accepted, I believe Barry is revising it.  I believe the `=>` part was viewed positively, other parts (like unary `>>`) less so.

Comment: @w.f. ping, see above

Answer (score 17):

Since c++17 there is always a constexpr lambda workaround if you really need to do sfinae inline:

```
#include <utility>

template <class Lambda, class... Ts>
constexpr auto test_sfinae(Lambda lambda, Ts&&...) 
    -> decltype(lambda(std::declval<Ts>()...), bool{}) { return true; }
constexpr bool test_sfinae(...)  { return false; }

template <class T>
constexpr bool bar(T var) {
    if constexpr(test_sfinae([](auto v) -> decltype(v.foo()){}, var))
       return true;
    return false;
}

struct A {
    void foo() {}
};

struct B { };

int main() {
    static_assert(bar(A{}));
    static_assert(!bar(B{}));
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V69lEKRrHxA4lnfc)

Comment: Note that `declval<Ts&>()` is an lvalue reference, so if the function you test does not accept non-const lvalue reference, the test will fail.

Comment: @IgorR. You're right but we have the adventage that we're creating the lambda `test_sfinae` will test. Still I'll have to think about it as it's far from being perfect.

Comment: @IgorR. I removed the reference in `declval` now it is up to lambda creator if he'd like to operate on references or on values. If the copy constructor is explicitly deleted lambda will match only when accepting reference i.e. `[](auto &v)`, `[](const auto &v)` or `[](auto &&v)`

Answer (score 3):

You can also reduce the amount of code by using [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

In your example, the code would then look like:

```
template <class T>
using has_foo_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());

if constexpr(is_detected_v<has_foo_t,decltype(var)>)
  var.foo();
```

Comment: It works! :) Though are you sure this is c++17 feature?

Comment: @W.F.: It's an experimental feature. It's not standardized yet.